# How to move/copy all the objects from one IList to other

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` project. I have `ViewModel` which is :

```
public class SectionModel
{
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public IList<Document>  Documents { get; set;}
}
```

then in my action I have :

```
Menu menu = unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetById(Id);
IList<Document> docs = unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetBy(x => x.MenuID ==  menu.MenuID).ToList();
                SectionModel model = new SectionModel();
                model.Menu = menu;//???
                model.Documents = docs;//???
```

So `menu` and `docs` are fetched from the database. The when I create new instance of `SectionModel` I want to pass the values but I'm not sure what's the proper way. In fact what is the way to assign the single object `menu` and the `IList<Document> docs`?

I was thinking of `model.Menu.Add(menu)` and then some foreach like:

```
foreach (var doc in docs)
{
  model.Documents.Add(doc);
}
```

but I'm not sure that's the proper way to do this.

Comment: You should try `binding` or `mapping` the items. Check `Automapper`

Comment: you could also maybe do a cast too.

Comment: @Leron: Check out my answer for an counter argument. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend interfaces  if your code should inter-operate with others projects but underneath  you are using always  `List<T>`

you have  to change this

```
 public class SectionModel
{
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public List<Document>  Documents { get; set;}
}
```

and use

```
  model.Documents.AddRange(docs);
```

Comment: does  your documents  of type List<T>

Comment: It's `IList` as you can see. Do you suggest to change it to `List` and just use `AddRange`?

Comment: you should change  it as List<T>   so you can use the AddRange

Comment: @JulieShannon: No, this might smell. You should not change IList to List just for using `AddRange`, particularly if its large. @Leron: `Automapper` is a good way to do this. Check out.

Comment: @Leron see the answer  of Moo-Juice to understand  is the best way

Comment: @JulieShannon Thanks, I think I just gonna use `List`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a common thread of thought I see all the time, about using interfaces to declare lists (or some other collection type) when declaring properties.  I understand the motivation to do this, should you ever decide to throw the standard .NET `List<>` class in favour of your home-grown.

I've yet to see a decent reason for this.  You're falling foul of the "let's abstract everything away in all circumstances, even if they are not particularly relevant" idiom.  (And let us not forget that interfaces on POCOs are not particularly ORM-friendly.)

If I were designing an API, I *might* use `IList`, even if everything worked with a `List` internally.  Truth is, it's a bit of a misnomer.  I've never had cause to use an `IList<>` because that's all it is... a programmatic misnomer.

As Julie says, swap out that interface and put a decent class in there (`List<>`, for example)..  not only is it concrete, but you can then use it as it should be used.  People love to band about the terms of `interfaces always in case I change my mind` but that just stinks of bad design.

Don't be afraid to use a real, concrete class.

Comment: Indeed with some PHP and Java background it's making impression that in C# interfaces are used much more frequently. To be honest I'm not sure how to choose, I think one need decent understanding about the language to really know the pro and cons for each case but this does not change the fact that indeed interfaces are used a lot.

Comment: @Moo-juice: Sorry, I don't entirely agree. Why should you change your `model` object? After all, its sole purpose is to represent the information and `IList` looks good for me here. Just for using the `AddRange` extension method, changing to `List` looks un-necessary.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. a fair point - but if we're going down that route then it surely the collection matters beyond the interface level?  you're saying that making it `List` instead of `IList` purely because of a single method is the reasoning.  We're talking POCOs here and I hope to hell I just get a list of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider to use `AutoMapper`, here's the code:

First, make sure you have `AutoMapper` installed. Use `package-manager` and type command `package-install AutoMapper`.

```
var anonymous = new { 
  Menu = unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetById(Id);, 
  Documents = unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetBy(x => x.MenuID ==  menu.MenuID).ToList(); 
};


  var sectionModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<SectionModel>(anonymous);
```

Any why I suggest to use this ?

Point 1: `IList` is fine here. Somebody (or you) had put there during design and it's just fine. According to me, changing to `List` is unnecessary. Your `model` object is just there to put the information and `IList` is fine because your `sectionmodel` class is not going to change or delete any entry from it. Since its just there for `enumeration` its fine.

Point 2: You can do the manual mapping. But, `AutoMapper` just maintains code readable.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. I have never worked with `AutoMapper` before. It seems interesting though. Despite that I was seeking for more natural C# approach. Using third party lib seem a bit overkill for this.